# Angular how to pass array in to component

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I pass an array from template to component file. I have an `if` condition which is dependent on the index of the loop. Please help me to find the right approach. Something like this 
https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7638

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of list_value | keyvalue; let i=index;" (click)="getListValue(i,data)">
  <li>
  <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of data.value" *ngIf="data[i].active">
     <li>
  <ul>
<ul>
```

example.componet.ts file

```
export class SomeComponent{

   list_value: Array<any> = [];
   active: boolean;

   getListValue(index: String, data: any) {
       console.log("Test",data[index]);
       list_value[index].active = !list_value[index].active
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want to achieve a sloution like this http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7638/

Answer (score 2):

One of the way to pass data to component is by using `@input` in angular like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of list_value | keyvalue; let i=index;" (click)="getListValue(i,data)">
  <li>
  <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of data.value" *ngIf="data[i].active">
      <app-selector *ngSwitchCase="'observations'" [inputdata]=item></app-selector>

     <li>
```

and in your `component.ts` file which loads inside `*ngFor`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, NgModule, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-selector',
  templateUrl: './selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./selector.component.scss']
})
export class ObservationsComponent implements OnChanges{
  @Input() inputdata: any;
}
ngOnChanges() {
        console.log(this.inputdata)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the array, just pass the list_value. *ngFor is just like a for loop, it iterates over an array. Data itself maybe an array (as it is of type 'any'). But the index you are sending in the function is the index where data is in list_value[index]

Write `*ngIf="data.active"`

Also as it is shown in the link given, you don't need the index. Just write `data.active = !data.active`

Comment: Thanks for you reply.. I tried your solution and partially it works. The only problem is that that when we click on the new menu's item, the previous menu should be collapsed but that is not hapening...

Comment: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * 
as you are using *ngFor and *ngIf in the same line. use [hidden]='!data.active' in place of *ngIf

Comment: No i didnt get you.. How ngif will make sure the other menu is getting collapse like this https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7638

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully below code will helpful

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of list_value;let i=index" (click)="getListValue(i,data)">    
      <span>{{data.name}}</span>
      <ul>

                <li *ngFor="let subItem of data.subItems" [hidden]="!data.active">
                    <span>---{{subItem.name}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Component ts

```
   export class SomeComponent{
     list_value: Array<any> = [
            {          
                name: "Item1",
                subItems: [
                    {name: "SubItem1"},
                    {name: "SubItem2"}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Item2",            
                subItems: [
                    {name: "SubItem3"},
                    {name: "SubItem4"},
                    {name: "SubItem5"}
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Item3",
                subItems: [
                    {name: "SubItem6"}
                ]
            }
        ];;   
       getListValue(index: number, data: any) {      
           this.list_value[index].active = !this.list_value[index].active
       }
    }
```

Workign App 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtqnmh

Comment: This is coming as undefined..  this.list_value[index].active...     from where  are getting this "active" value

Comment: We are extending object inside getListValue function.